# Creating HDF5 compound attributes using h5py

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to create some simple HDF5 datasets that contain attributes with a compound datatype using h5py.  The goal is an attribute that has two integers.  Here are two example of attributes I'd like to create.

[image: File with desired attributes]

My attempts end up with an array of two values such as

[image: File with bad attribute]

How can I code this using h5py and get a single value that contains two integers?
Current code looks something like

```
dt_type = np.dtype({"names": ["val1"],"formats": [('<i4', 2)]})
# also tried   np.dtype({"names": ["val1", "val2"],"formats": [('<i4', 1), ('<i4', 1)]})
dataset.attrs.create('time.start', [('23', '3')], dtype=dt_type)
```

How can I specify the type or the attribute create to get the first example?

Comment: Did you `h5py` code work?  Error?  Wrong attribute?  Basically `h5py` writes and reads `numpy` arrays to the HDF5 file, with the needed translations.

Comment: The h5py code will generate the incorrect attribute.  I haven't figured out the magic syntax to produce an attribute of {int, int}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make an array with `dt_type`, you have to properly nest lists and tuples:

```
In [162]: arr = np.array([(['23','3'],)], dt_type)                                             
In [163]: arr                                                                                  
Out[163]: array([([23,  3],)], dtype=[('val1', '<i4', (2,))])
```

This is (1,) array with a compound dtype.  The dtype has 1 field, but 2 values within that field.

With the alternative dtype:

```
In [165]: dt2 = np.dtype({"names": ["val1", "val2"],"formats": ['<i4', '<i4']})                
In [166]: arr2 = np.array([('23','3',)], dt2)                                                  
In [167]: arr2                                                                                 
Out[167]: array([(23, 3)], dtype=[('val1', '<i4'), ('val2', '<i4')])
```

or the simplest array:

```
In [168]: arr3 = np.array([23,2])                                                              
In [169]: arr3                                                                                 
Out[169]: array([23,  2])
```

Writing to a dataset:

```
In [170]: ds.attrs.create('arr', arr)                                                          
In [172]: ds.attrs.create('arr2', arr2)                                                        
In [173]: ds.attrs.create('arr3', arr3)
```

check the fetch:

```
In [175]: ds.attrs['arr']                                                                      
Out[175]: array([([23,  3],)], dtype=[('val1', '<i4', (2,))])
In [176]: ds.attrs['arr2']                                                                     
Out[176]: array([(23, 3)], dtype=[('val1', '<i4'), ('val2', '<i4')])
In [177]: ds.attrs['arr3']                                                                     
Out[177]: array([23,  2])
```

dump:

```
1203:~/mypy$ h5dump compound.h5
HDF5 "compound.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
   DATASET "test" {
      DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I64LE
      DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 10 ) / ( 10 ) }
      DATA {
      (0): 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "arr" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
            H5T_ARRAY { [2] H5T_STD_I32LE } "val1";
         }
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( 1 ) }
         DATA {
         (0): {
               [ 23, 3 ]
            }
         }
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "arr2" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
            H5T_STD_I32LE "val1";
            H5T_STD_I32LE "val2";
         }
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 1 ) / ( 1 ) }
         DATA {
         (0): {
               23,
               3
            }
         }
      }
      ATTRIBUTE "arr3" {
         DATATYPE  H5T_STD_I64LE
         DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 2 ) / ( 2 ) }
         DATA {
         (0): 23, 2
         }
      }
   }
}
}
```