# Difference between numpy.arr((...)) and numpy.arr([...])

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

When calling numpy.array in the following two ways:

```
>>> np.array((1,2,3,4))
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.array([1,2,3,4])
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I notice it returns two seemingly identical ndarrays.
Are both of these ndarrays identical? Why?

Comment: Yes they read both from an iterable that yields the same numbers.

Comment: List and tuples don't really differ in the data they carry. They only differ by the features they are supporting. The only feature used in your code is to yield a sequence of items and that is supported by both.

Comment: When making a basic numpy array like this, they are the same.  When using a `compound dtype` (to make a `structured` array) they have different meanings.  See my recent answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174899/creating-hdf5-compound-attributes-using-h5py/60176463#60176463

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can behave in a general way here. Suppose we don't know what `X = np.array([1,2,3,4])` and `Y = np.array((1,2,3,4))` are.  If we print it, we can see an output which is the result of a secret built-in methods `X.__repr__` and `Y.__repr__`. You can see here for sure that both `X` and `Y` has the same representations. It doesn't mean, however, that they are the same because they can be instances of different classes with the same representations. To make it sure, I usually use `X.__class__` and `Y.__class__`. So both `X` and `Y` are instances of the same class `np.ndarray`.